# Unity 3D: how to freeze frame to explore the collision lines drawn by `Debug.DrawRay`?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

I tried this:

```c#
Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, collision.relativeVelocity, Color.white);
Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
```

the frame was frozen but the line was not displayed. Also, I tried to freeze in the `Update` immediately after drawing the line without success as well as after skipping the first `Update`.

Comment: Where are you calling this code? If it's e.g. `OnCollisionEnter` or something similar it will be called in only **1** frame and `Time.timeScale=0;` won't help much. Maybe just [debugging](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio) with a breakpoint would already be enough?

Comment: Yes, it's called in the `OnCollisionEnter `. The purpose is to see and understand what `collision.relativeVelocity` and `collision.impulse` mean and what their directions show. I hope that visualization could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) is only called once in the frame when the collision first occures.

[`Debug.DrawLine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) has an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) `duration` of  which by default is `0`

> How long the line should be visible for.

and

> The `duration` is the time (in seconds) for which the line will be visible after it is first displayed. **A duration of zero shows the line for just one frame.**

---

So you could pass e.g. `2` like

```c#
Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, collision.relativeVelocity, Color.white, 2.0f);
```

to make it stay visible for 2 seconds.

---

As alternative I would simply put the code in [`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) instead so it is called not only once but every frame while the collision occures.

---

For the question behind it the Unity API usually is a good startpoint:

- [`Collision.impulse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-impulse.html)

  > The total impulse applied to this contact pair to resolve the collision.
  >
  > The total impulse is obtained by summing up impulses applied at all contact points in this collision pair. To work out the total force applied you can divide the total impulse by the last frame's fixedDeltaTime.
- [`Collision.relativeVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html)

  > The relative linear velocity of the two colliding objects.

So the difference: `impulse` takes all individual contact/collision points into account where each might have different collision forces and directions while `relativeVelocity` only is the relative velocity between the object centers/pivot points (it doesn't matter).